# custom post type and taxonomy URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm using following code for my custom post type

```
function resources_custom() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Resources', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Resources', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New resources' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Resources' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Resources' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Resources' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Resources' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search resources' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No resources found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No resources found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Resources'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri(). '/images/image-empty.png',
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'resources', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'resources_custom' );
```

and use the following code for taxonomies,

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_resources_taxonomies', 0 );

function create_resources_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'cat', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'cat', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search category' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All category' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Sections' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'cat',
        'with_front' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'resources' ), $args );
}
```

Well, my url for custom post archive is :
example.com/resources
for custom post taxonomies is :
example.com/cat/test-taxonomy
and for posts is :
example.com/resources/test-post

is there any way to use "resources" instead of "cat"? So the custom post taxonomies URL should be like this :
example.com/resources/test-taxonomy

Comment: What if a time comes when you have a post and a term with the same slug? WordPress will look for `/resources/that-slug` and it won't know which to pull up, you can do something like `'slug' => '/resources/cat'` or something similar.

Comment: it works, what about if i use just resources without cat? it doesn't work for single post type when i changed it to just resources.

Comment: Nope, you cannot have a taxonomy with the same name as a page. There are a bunch of Q/A that give great responses if you search - here's [one I asked awhile back](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119241/custom-taxonomy-leads-to-404-page-permalink-structure-flushed) because I agree it is a little confusing.