# 404 for a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, register-taxonomy

Why do I get 404 for my custom taxonomy?

```
add_action('init', 'custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite');
function custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action('init', 'create_publication_categories');
function create_publication_categories() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Categories'),
        'has_archive' =>  true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'topics',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
    );
    $postTypes = array(
        'publication'
    );
    $taxonomy = 'publication';
    register_taxonomy($taxonomy, $postTypes, $args);
}
```

So I have the template called `taxonomy-publication.php`, but I still get 404.

I have reset the permalink following [this](https://kriesi.at/support/topic/custom-taxonomy-results-in-404-error/). And other answers such as [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119241/custom-taxonomy-leads-to-404-page-permalink-structure-flushed) and [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomies-not-reading-templates-for-it/).

But I still get 404. Any ideas what I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the same slug `publication` for custom taxonomy and custom post type. Slug should be **unique**.

---

Another thing (not related with 404) is the `flush_rules`. As you can read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage) flush on the `init` hook is bad idea.

> **Important**:
>
> - Flushing the rewrite rules is an expensive operation, there are tutorials and examples that suggest executing it on the `init` hook. **This is bad practice**. It should be executed either on the 'shutdown' hook, or on plugin/theme (de)activation.
> - Flush rules once (it's better to store the state in option, instead of `activation` or `deactivation`, because on MultiSite they are useless), or when you know that the rewrite rules need to be changed. **Don't do it on any hook that will triggered on a routine basis**. More detail information in the comments on WP Engineer's post: Custom Post Type and Permalink
> - Make sure custom post types and taxonomies are **properly registered before** flushing rewrite rules, especially during plugin activation: Activation Checklist for WordPress Plugin Developers (inaccessible)

**Example**

Flush rules on theme activation:

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite' );
function custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. btw, how do I flush properly then if `flush on the init hook is bad idea`.?

Comment: You can use `after_switch_theme` action hook or use option to store flush status. Before `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules()` check if option (e.g `get_option('flush_done', 0) == 0`) exists and save after flush (`update_option('flush_done', 1)`).  @laukok

Comment: or flush them manually by saving the settings>permalinks page..